# How to get buttons from array (android)?

Tags: android, arrays

I need help.
I have text array in arrays.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <resources>
     <string-array name="firstarray">
         <item value="0">firs titem</item>
         <item value="1">second item</item>
         <item value="2">third item</item>
         <item value="3">fourth item</item>
     </string-array>
 </resources>
```

And in java file i read this array to file

```
  public class cat extends Activity {
      String [] listView;
      ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

        @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.cat);

            listView = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.firstarray);

       } }
```

In XML i have List code

```
 <ListView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="439dp"
         android:id="@+id/listView"
         android:entries="@array/firstarray"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
         style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ListView"
         android:scrollbars="none" />
```

But today I want to output a button instead of a list. How to make it easier?

Comment: where is Button here?

Comment: Make a custom adapter with a custom list item view which contains a button. Here is an example of a custom adapter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166497/custom-adapter-for-list-view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create button array like this

```
Button[] buttons=new Button[5];
final LinearLayout linearLayout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);

for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
            Button button=new Button(this);
            button.setText(""+i);
            button.setOnClickListener(onclicklistener);
            linearLayout.addView(button);
        }

onclicklistener = new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            }
});
```

Comment: Tnx,I have error "cannot resolve symbol linearLayout" and "cannot resolve symbol onclicklistener"Can you explain to a beginner?

Comment: have you added LinearLayout in your xml?

Comment: This my xml 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="7dp"
    android:scrollbars="none" >
    
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">
        
.....

Comment: The buttons should be in XML with your code? Can you show a working example?

Comment: plz help me. roblem with **onclicklistener** only

Comment: This might be useful to you http://www.android-examples.com/create-button-dynamically-through-mainactivity-in-android/

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help. I got to bring the buttons automatically. But as they are associated with an array **firstarray**? To convey the press value in the new Activity, and knock called as an array elements?

```
String[] mTestArray;
mTestArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.firstarray);
length =getResources().getStringArray(R.array.firstarray).length
Button[] buttons=new Button[length];
        final LinearLayout linearLayout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.buttonlayout);

        for(int i=0;i<length;i++){

            Button button=new Button(this);
            button.setId(i);
            final int id_ = button.getId();
            button.setText(mTestArray[id_]);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),
                            "Button clicked index = " + id_, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
            });
            linearLayout.addView(button);
        }
```